# Local images to base64 and IE

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, local

for a wep-app i'm writing i need to get de base64 encoding of a file without sending any information to the server.
i got everything working on firefox and chrome but ofcourse IE is not working.

the code is as follows:

```
1  $(document).ready(function() {
2      $("#in").change(load_picture);
3  });
4 
5  function loaded_picture(evt)
6  {
7      var data = evt.target.result;
8      $("body").append("<img src='"+data+"' width='100'  />");
9      console.log(data);
10 }
11 
12 function load_picture(evt)
13 {
14     console.log(evt);
15     var f = evt.target.files[0];
16     var reader = new FileReader();
17     reader.onload = loaded_picture;
18     reader.readAsDataURL(f);
19 }
```

i'm using the newest jquery,
there is a input box of type file in the body with id="#in".

Firefox works like a charm but in IE there does not seem to be a evt.target.files array.
is there any way to do the same in IE?

Tanx

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think your best bet would be to use Chrome frame or something like [this](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-sexy/) as per Dean Edwards. Since IE9- version does not support the feature that you are looking for.